# How to wait until code is done. iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I can call some selector by this code

```
[self performSelector:<#(SEL)#> onThread:<#(NSThread *)#> withObject:<#(id)#> waitUntilDone:<#(BOOL)#>]
```

and the Thread will wait until this selector is working (if I set waitUntilDone:YES). My question is - Can i wait until some code is done?

for example. I have some subview, which loads with animation. Animation duration is 2 sec. And if i make some actions on background view, while animating, i have an error. I'd like to wait until animation is over. And I can't to make a selector, and use

```
[self performSelector:<#(SEL)#> onThread:<#(NSThread *)#> withObject:<#(id)#> waitUntilDone:<#(BOOL)#>]
```

Any suggestions? )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this way

```
-(void)waitUntilDone:(void(^)(void))waitBlock {
    //use your statement or call method here
    if(waitBlock){
        waitBlock();
    }
}
```

And you need to use it as

```
[self.tableView waitUntilDone:^{
    //call the required method here                                            
}];
```

Answer (score 2):

`UIView` animation gives this to you in the form of the block style animation

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f
                 animations:^{
                   // animations
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                   // run code when the animation is finished
                 }];
```

Answer (score 1):

Wait until animation gets finished & then do rest of the things :

For eg:

```
   [UIView animateWithDuration:duration
    animations:^
    {
       //DO ANIMATION ADJUSTMENTS HERE
    }
    completion:^(BOOL finished)
    {
        //ANIMATION DID FINISH -- DO YOUR STUFF
    }];
```